# ¿Como sobrecargar operadores correctamente en C#?

Tags: c#, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Estoy intentando hacer una sobrecarga de operadores en una clase. Me estaba guiando por el ejemplo que da Microsoft en su página.

[Sobrecarga de operadores (referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Pero me están saliendo unos errores y no sé como arreglarlo:

> DataObject.cs(8,49): error CS1002: Se esperaba ;
> DataObject.cs(8,57): error CS1519: El token '+' no es válido en una clase, struct o declaración de miembro de interfaz
> DataObject.cs(8,65): error CS1519: El token ';' no es válido en una clase, struct o declaración de miembro de interfaz

Este es mi código:

```
//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class DataObject<T> 
{
    private T data;
    public static DataObject<T> operator +(DataObject<T> b) => data + b.data;
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Int : DataObject<int>
{ 

}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Calcula
{
    public Int Suma(Int a, Int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public void Suma(Int a, Int b, Int result)
    {
        result = a + b;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int a = new Int();
        Int b = new Int();
        Int result = new Int();

        Calcula calcula = new Calcula();

        a = 5;
        b = 7;

        calcula.Suma(a, b, result);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);


        a = 3;
        b = 6;

        result = calcula.Suma(a, b);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);        

    }
}
```

¿Alguien sabría decirme como hacer esto correctamente?
Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar algo como lo que te mostraré más abajo.

La clave es utilizar métodos que retornan referencias. Aquí la documentación oficial [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns)

```cs
public class Creator
{
   public ref CustomInt Create(ref CustomInt i)
      => ref i;

   public CustomInt Create(int i)
      => new CustomInt { Data = i };               
}

public class Operator
{
   public ref CustomInt Sum(ref CustomInt i, params CustomInt[] ints)
   {
      foreach (var item in ints)
      {
         i.Data += item.Data;
      }
            
      return ref i;
   }

   public ref CustomInt Sum(ref CustomInt i, params int[] ints)
   {
      foreach (var item in ints)
      {
         i.Data += item;
      }
            
      return ref i;
    }
}

public class CustomInt
{
    private static readonly Creator _creator = new Creator();
    public static readonly Operator Operator = new Operator();

    public int Data { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator int(CustomInt d)
       => _creator.Create(ref d);

    public static implicit operator CustomInt(int d)
       => _creator.Create(d);

    public static CustomInt operator +(CustomInt a, CustomInt b)
       => Operator.Sum(ref a, b);

    public static CustomInt operator +(CustomInt a, int b)
       => Operator.Sum(ref a, b);

    public override string ToString()
       => Data.ToString();

    public void Clear()
       => this.Data = 0;
}
```

Y aquí tienes el método Main, en dónde se realizan diferentes Tests y, al parecer, cumple con lo que deseas:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   // Declaracion de variables
   CustomInt ciSumando_1;
   CustomInt ciSumando_2;
   CustomInt ciResult;
   CustomInt ciResultRef;
   int intSumando_1;
   int intSumando_2;
   int intSumandi_1_Ref;

   // Asignacion de valores
   ciResult = new CustomInt();
   ciResultRef = ciResult;
   ciSumando_1 = 5;
   ciSumando_2 = 7;
   intSumando_1 = 1;
   intSumando_2 = 2;
   intSumandi_1_Ref = intSumando_1;

   // Prueba de referencia entre int's
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - ints] :  " + Object.ReferenceEquals(intSumando_1, intSumandi_1_Ref));
   Console.WriteLine("");

   // Suma de CustomInts utilizando Operator para CustomInt e ints y pruba de referencia entre CustomInts ... (1)
   ciResult.Clear();
   int initialResultValue = ciResult.Data;
   ciResult = CustomInt.Operator.Sum(ref ciResult, ciSumando_1, ciSumando_2);
   Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {initialResultValue} + {ciSumando_1} + {ciSumando_2} = {ciResult}");
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - Operator(CustomInt, CustomInt, CustomInt)] :   " + Object.ReferenceEquals(ciResultRef, ciResult));
   Console.WriteLine("");

   // Cambio de valores CustomInts
   ciSumando_1 = 3;
   ciSumando_2 = 6;

   // Misma prueba que (1)
   ciResult.Clear();
   initialResultValue = ciResult.Data;
   ciResult = CustomInt.Operator.Sum(ref ciResult, ciSumando_1, ciSumando_2);
   Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {initialResultValue} + {ciSumando_1} + {ciSumando_2} = {ciResult}");
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - Operator(CustomInt, CustomInt, CustomInt) - Previa reasignacion de valores a operandos] : " + Object.ReferenceEquals(ciResultRef, ciResult));
   Console.WriteLine("");

   //  Suma de CustomInt e ints utilizando Operator y pruba de referencia entre CustomInts ... (@)
   ciResult.Clear();
   initialResultValue = ciResult.Data;
   ciResult = CustomInt.Operator.Sum(ref ciResult, intSumando_1, intSumando_2);
   Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {initialResultValue} + {intSumando_1} + {intSumando_2} = {ciResult}");
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - Operator(CustomInt, int, int)] :" + Object.ReferenceEquals(ciResultRef, ciResult));
   Console.WriteLine("");

   // Suma de CustomInts utilizando operador +
   ciResult.Clear();
   initialResultValue = ciResult.Data;
   ciResult += ciSumando_1;
   ciResult += ciSumando_2;
   Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {initialResultValue} + {ciSumando_1} + {ciSumando_2} = {ciResult}");
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - +(CustomInt, CustomInt, CustomInt)] : " + Object.ReferenceEquals(ciResultRef, ciResult));
   Console.WriteLine("");

   // Suma de ints y CustomInts utilizando operador +
   ciResult.Clear();
   initialResultValue = ciResult.Data;
   ciResult += intSumando_1;
   ciResult += intSumando_2;
   Console.WriteLine($"Operation: {initialResultValue} + {intSumando_1} + {intSumando_2} = {ciResult}");
   Console.WriteLine("[Test Referencias - +(CustomInt, int, int)] : " + Object.ReferenceEquals(ciResultRef, ciResult));
   Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

No olvides agregar validaciones a los métodos de la clase Operator.

Comment: Es genial!! Muchas gracias Carlos!!

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento he llegado a esta solución... pero no me gusta porque pierdo las instancias de los objetos originales y me gustaría conservarlas... Si alguien sabe como hacer lo mismo pero consevando las instacias y pone su respuesta aquí se la aceptaré.

NOTA: no me sirve una instancia estática porque si no solo puedo declarar un solo objeto.

```
//-------------------------------------------------- 


using System.Collections.Generic;

using System;

//-------------------------------------------------- 


public class Int
{
    private Int instance;
    private int data;

    public Int()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(Int d)
    {
        return d.data;
    }
    
    public static implicit operator Int(int d)
    {
        return new Int { data = d };
    }

    public static Int operator +(Int a, Int b)
    {
        //return new Int { data = a.data + b.data };
        a.data = a.data + b.data;
        return a;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return data.ToString();
    }

    public static Int operator +(Int a, int b)
    {
        //return new Int { data = a.data + b };
        a.data = a.data + b;
        return a;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 


public class Calcula
{
    
    public Int Suma(Int a, Int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    
    public void Suma(Int a, Int b, out Int result)
    {
        result = (a + b);
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 


public class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int a = new Int();
        Int b = new Int();
        Int result = new Int();
        Int resultRef = result;


        Console.Write("\n " + Object.ReferenceEquals(resultRef, result));

        Calcula calcula = new Calcula();

        a = 5;
        b = 7;

        calcula.Suma(a, b, out result);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);

        a = 3;
        b = 6;

        result = calcula.Suma(a, b);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);


        Console.Write("\n " + Object.ReferenceEquals(resultRef, result));

    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

//C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe DataObject.cs

//--------------------------------------------------
```

Salida del programa:

> True
> result=12
> result=9
> False

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Estás escribiendo algo como:  int c = 2; int d = c;  y si evaluas Object.ReferenceEquals(c, d)); será False. Este comportamiento es de tipos inmutables y los overloadings están orientados a ello, por lo que podrías lograrlo de otra manera (un wrapper) pero no directamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.Investigaré sobre ello. Lo que estoy buscando es que se comporte como un puntero pero sin tener que meterme en un entorno inseguro. Sé que los objetos en C# se pasan por referencia y los struct no. Me está dando false porque para poder usar el singo igual tuve que implementar el operador implicito que está haciendo un "new" y por eso devuelve una referencia diferente. Si pudiera devolver la referencia del objeto original daría true. Pero como es una funcion estatica no veo la forma de hacerlo a no ser que use un singleton... lo cual no me interesa tampoco en este caso.

Comment: has resuelto este problema?

Comment: Se podría solucionar con un indexer **public int this[int index] { get => data[index]; }** pero aunque funcionaría tengo la impresión de que no es la solución mas elegante...  Aun estoy abierto a otras ideas!! Saludos!!